# Cannot boot Virtual Machine beyond the 1st time

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I'm trying to run a Windows Server 2003 + SP2 Virtual Machine with Virtual PC.
So I created a new Virtual Machine, from the Virtual PC menu, selecting the VMHD file (which contains the operation system).

The first time I run it, everything's fine. 
But after I restart it, I get a blue screen of death every time on the Windows loading screen, which says:

"A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer.

TRAP_CAUSE_UNKNOWN

If this is the first time you've seen this Stop error screen, restart your computer. If this screen appears again, follow these steps:

Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed.
If this is a new installation, ask your hardware or software manufacturer for any Windows updates you might need."

I suppose it may be trying to load new hardware (which didn't happen the 1st time it booted).
I even tried to run it again, using another copy of the original VMHD file), and this time uninstalled the hardware marked with a "?" on the device manager, but that didn't fix the problem.

Any clues on how to solve this?

Comment: Is it an x86 OS that you've installed?

Comment: Yes, 32-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to run an old vhd image of Windows Server 2003 on Windows 7. The solution was to find the old vsv settings file that went with it and copy it into the same directory as the vhd.

Perhaps your settings file is failing to save and therefore the boot cannot complete on subsequent tries?